# Why are my svg's copying each other when used inline?

Tags: svg, inline

I'm attempting to inline these svg images into my site, but in testing they appear to be copying each other. I know next to nothing about SVG's so bear with me. They were all converted from png on vectormagic. Here is an example http://pelicandrones1.wpengine.com/test.html

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same id value in the same document which is invalid. E.g. id="p1"